# SIM settings icon always on notification bar

Tags: sim-card

I bought an imported HTC Desire about 6 months ago and put my New Zealand Vodafone SIM in it. When I start up the phone, there's nothing in the noticication bar as you'd expect. Then, after a call is made or data connection initiates, an icon appears that looks like a SIM card with a cog next to it. I assume it's something to do with SIM settings. When I drag the notification bar down and click on it, nothing happens.

It's not a big deal, but I'd like to get rid of it if I can!

Don't know if it matters, but since I upgraded to Gingerbread, most of the icons in the notification bar are grey rather than white, but this one has remained white.

The phone is running the official HTC Desire Gingerbread upgrade - Android 2.3.3.

Update: Photos of the icon:

[image: Photo 1]
[image: Photo 2]

Comment: Obviously the phone is unlocked if it makes calls, but is it still running firmware from another region or carrier? That would likely explain it.

Comment: It's running the official HTC Gingerbread firmware - assume that's not carrier- or region-specific... That said, I assume it's my carrier trying to send me some settings but the phone can't read them or ignore them or something...

Comment: Usually that symbol means it's preparing the sd card. I always get it when I restart my phone as it's loading all the apps/wallpaper that I have.

Comment: Are you sure it is a sim related icon and not a micro SD card icon ? Does it have any text with the icon ?

Comment: Could you make photo or another image of this icon? I'd like to take a look at it.

Comment: @nathpilland - Pretty sure it's not the preparing SD icon, I see that on startup too.

Comment: @George - have added photo links just now...

Answer (score 3):

That is the SD card icon not the sim card icon.

Perhaps your phone does not recognise the SD card, or the card needs reformatting to be used with the phone.

Or you don't have an SD card inserted.

**EDIT**

After further [research](http://androidforums.com/htc-magic/6652-question-about-notifcation-icon.html):

That icon is called "stat_notify_sim_toolkit." It is used in just two places, both methods inside com.android.server.MountService:

notifyMediaUnmounted()
notifyMeadiaChecking()

Tracing these methods backwards, I see that the MountService calls them when either:

1) a volume is detected as not mounted
2) it is checking to see if a volume is mounted

Num. 2 should only take a few seconds at longest.

So, "something" is not mounted properly, though I cannot guarantee that is the SIM that is having a problem.

You should remove and re-insert all plugable items (SIM, SD).

---

Another option recommends:

> settings > applications > manage applications > SIM Toolkit > Select Force Stop button

If this removed the icon 'temporarily' at least it confirms it's a **SIM** problem and not SD.

**EDIT 2**

Someone has a recommended solution for NON-ROOTED phone's here:
(I cannot verify this method as I haven't tested it)

[SimCard Notification Icon Fix](http://forum.vodafone.co.nz/topic/6080-sim-card-notification-icon-in-android-phone/page__view__findpost__p__61261)

For rooted phones simply use Titanium Backup and *FREEZE* the app: Sim Toolkit

Comment: I have an SD card in there and it works fine... There is a different icon there when it says "Preparing SD card" etc...

Comment: @x3ja Edited hope you can fix it!

Comment: cool thanks! Yes, force stopping SIM Tolkit removes the icon temporarily (comes back after a few seconds). As for the temporary root option - will look at that too - interesting that it's on the Vodafone NZ forums - I'm on Vodafone NZ too... perhaps it's unique to us kiwi Vodafoners?